# Я пытаюсь написать код для подсчета разницы входа и выхода, в минутах

Tags: python, циклы, дата, datetime, время

Я пытался написать код для подсчета разницы входа и выхода, если рабочие часы с 9:00 по 18:00 и не забывая, что сб-вс выходные дни.
У меня подсчитывается все время, а должно так "вход: 16-05-2022 12:00:00 и выход: 17-05-2022 11:23:00"
Помогите пожалуйста как это можно реализовать?

Мой код:

```
def find_minutes(start, end):
    temp = end - start
    days = temp.days
    for i in range(1 ,days+1):     
        now = start + datetime.timedelta(i)
        if now.strftime("%A") in ["Saturday", 'Sunday']:
            temp -= datetime.timedelta(1)
    return temp        

start = datetime.datetime.strptime(input(), "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S")
end = datetime.datetime.strptime(input(), "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S")

print(F"{int(find_minutes(start, end).total_seconds()//60)} minutes")
```

Comment: `а должно так "вход: 16-05-2022 12:00:00 и выход: 17-05-2022 11:23:00"` так и делайте по формату, что-то вроде: `print(f"вход: {start:%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S} и выход: {end:%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S}")`

Comment: Ну, я же так и делаю, но не получается посчитать минуты с учетом рабочих часов

Comment: Не увидел, чтобы вы такое делали. Напишите, пожалуйста, входные данные и ожидаемый результат

Comment: Пример:
"вход: 16-05-2022 12:00:00 и выход: 17-05-2022 12:32:00".
Вот пожалуйста входные данные

Comment: Вы напишите какой ответ вы хотите получить при указанных вами данных. Прям в вопрос добавьте. Так будет проще. Думаю что половина сюда зашедших не поняла какого результата Вы добиваетесь

Comment: Надо посчитать разницу входа и выхода в минутах не учитывая не рабочие часы (только 9:00-18:00) и сб-вс.

Comment: Тоесть если человек вошел в 17:50 пятницы а вышел в 9:10 понедельника то результат должен быть 20. Я правильно понял?

Comment: Да, вы правильно поняли

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вы проверяете день недели, но не проверяете время. Добавьте в цикл проверку времени, например как-то так:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt, timedelta as td, time

start = dt.fromisoformat('2022-05-17 17:55:00')
end = dt.fromisoformat('2022-05-17 20:00:00')
time_start = time.fromisoformat('09:00')
time_end = time.fromisoformat('18:00')

res = 0
t = start
while (t:=t+td(minutes=1))<=end:
    if t.weekday()<5 and time_start<=t.time()<=time_end:
        res+=1 
print(res)  # 5
```

или с помощью pandas примерно так:

```
import pandas as pd

dates = pd.date_range('2022-05-17 17:55:00', '2022-05-17 20:00:00', freq='T')
res = len(dates[(dates.time>=time_start)&(dates.time<time_end)&(dates.weekday<5)])

print(res)  # 5
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам, хороший человек!
Вы мне помогли✊

Comment: с '2022-05-13 17:50:00' по '2022-05-16 09:10:00' 21 минута получится

Comment: @Namerek, да минута лишняя, это можно поправить

Answer (score 1):

`pip install python-dateutil`

```py
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.rrule import *
from dateutil.parser import parse
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def worktime_count(start: datetime, end: datetime, unit=MINUTELY):
    return len(
        [
            *rrule(
                unit,
                start,
                until=end - relativedelta(minutes=1),
                byweekday=range(0, 5),
                byhour=range(9, 18),
                wkst=MO
            )
        ]
    )
print(
    worktime_count(
        parse('2022-05-13 17:50:00'),
        parse('2022-05-16 09:10:00')
    )
)
# 20
print(
    worktime_count(
        parse('2022-05-13 17:50:00'),
        parse('2022-05-13 18:00:00')
    )
)
# 10
```

> [Ссылка на доку](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rrule.html?highlight=rrule#module-dateutil.rrule)

Comment: То есть здесь, если 6 после 5, шестой день месяца, 9-ка после 5, это 9-ый день месяца (2022, 5, 9, 9, 10)?

Comment: datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 9, 9, 0), # <-- Вот тут 21-я минута
Воот здесь, (9, 9, 0) что означает?
Первая 9 и вторая 9

Comment: @Coder, переделал ответ, посмотрите. Исправил появление лишней минуты

Comment: @Coder, Вы вероятно не под тем ответом написали комментарий. В этом нет ни `while` ни `pandas` (и не было)

Comment: @Coder, что касается моего ответа, для этой библиотеки задокументировано, что диапазон включает верхнюю границу времени, что и вызывало ошибку. Просто принудительно сократил диапазон на минуту. Теперь считает правиильно

Comment: Прошу прощения, немного запутался.
Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @Coder, что касается ответа который выше, просто сделайте тоже самое (сократите верхнюю границу диапазона на минуту после получения параметра). Просто pandas для работы со временем использует python-dateutil поэтому и природа данной проблемы, думаю что одинаковая