# python-dateutil подсчет рабочих часов

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

Сегодня был задан интересный для меня [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1410712/%d0%af-%d0%bf%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%b2%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%85) о подсчете рабочего времени в минутах.
*Я написал ответ основанный на использовании библиотеки `python-dateutil`*

```py
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.rrule import *
from dateutil.parser import parse


def worktime_count(start: datetime, end: datetime, unit=MINUTELY):
    return len(
        [
            *rrule(
                unit,
                start,
                until=end,
                byweekday=range(0, 5),
                byhour=range(9, 18),
                wkst=MO
            )
        ]
    )


print(
    worktime_count(
        parse('2022-05-13 17:50:00'),
        parse('2022-05-16 09:10:00')
    )
)
# 21
print(
    worktime_count(
        parse('2022-05-13 17:50:00'),
        parse('2022-05-13 18:00:00')
    )
)
# 10
# Поэтому просто -1 к результату не катит
```

> На мой взгляд ответ должен быть 20 (думаю Вы со мной согласитесь).
> Посему мой ответ я удалил

*Если сделать частоту генерации точек времени посекундной и потом длину списка // 60,

то ответ будет корректным.*

```py
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.rrule import *
from dateutil.parser import parse


def worktime_count(start: datetime, end: datetime, unit=SECONDLY):
    return len(
        [
            *rrule(
                unit,
                start,
                until=end,
                byweekday=range(0, 5),
                byhour=range(9, 18),
                wkst=MO
            )
        ]
    ) // 60


print(
    worktime_count(
        parse('2022-05-13 17:50:00'),
        parse('2022-05-16 09:10:00')
    )
)
# 20

print(
    worktime_count(
        parse('2022-05-13 17:50:00'),
        parse('2022-05-13 18:00:00')
    )
)
# 10
```

**Может быть есть у кого мысли как добиться правильного результата при поминутной частоте?**

> на всякий случай [ссылка на доку](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rrule.html?highlight=rrule#module-dateutil.rrule)

Comment: На всякий случай  (не вдаваясь в `python-dateutil`): а ответ 20 - точно корректный? Если мы говорим о рабочих минутах, то начинается рабочий час в 00 минут, а заканчивается в 59. Тогда с 17:50 по 17:59 пройдёт 10 минут, а с 9:00 по 9:10 - 11 минут.

Comment: Минута это не граница - минута это интервал так вот в часе интервалов 60

Comment: @Сергей, Если с 9:00 по 9:10 то если на момент ухода было 9:10:30 к примеру, то 11-я минута не полная а соответственно полных минут 10

Comment: @Сергей, у меня с пальцами что-то. 10 получается

Comment: Да, если неполная, то 10. Как писал, я на всякий случай указал на возможность ошибки. В табельном учёте часто путаются с этим. Только возможно, что `python-dateutil` по той же логике построен, что я написал.

Comment: @Сергей, воот. И с подсчетом через секунды и округлением все работает. А хочется что-бы "по феншую" Мало-ли какую фишку либы упустил

Comment: А нельзя ли посмотреть на этот посекундный результат до отбрасывания дробной части? Там, случаем, не 59 секунд отбрасывается?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136379/discussion-between-namerek-and-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### @Сергей, спасибо, натолкнули на мысль.

*Задача свелась к тому, чтобы не забирать последний элемент, если он находится в диапазоне рабочего времени. Для этого перед применением параметра конечной даты уменьшаем ее на минуту*

```py
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.rrule import *
from dateutil.parser import parse
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def worktime_count(start: datetime, end: datetime, unit=MINUTELY):
    return len(
        [
            *rrule(
                unit,
                start,
                until=end - relativedelta(minutes=1),
                byweekday=range(0, 5),
                byhour=range(9, 18),
                wkst=MO
            )
        ]
    )
print(
    worktime_count(
        parse('2022-05-13 17:50:00'),
        parse('2022-05-16 09:10:00')
    )
)
# 20
print(
    worktime_count(
        parse('2022-05-13 17:50:00'),
        parse('2022-05-13 18:00:00')
    )
)
# 10
```